# NoSuchMethodError com FirebaseMessaging

Tags: android

Estou obtendo o seguindo erro ao executar meu app:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal, PID: 29233
                                                                              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzjt(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId' appears in /data/app/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal-1/base.apk)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

A linha que da erro é essa:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("todos");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("live");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("comunicados");
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("videos");
```

Estava funcionando até ontem, eu acrescentei algumas coisas no código e agora ta dando esse erro quando abre o app, não entendo o porque, eu fiz algumas pesquisas e a maioria das respostas era colocar a mesma versão pra todos os compile no gradle, porem o meu já esta assim.

meu gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
```

Comment: Pelo li em outra comunidade stack, pode ser erro nas versões de seus componentes. Verifique esses componentes novos que você adicionou.

Comment: Unica coisa que adicionei foi o GcmNetworkManager com a versão:  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4' que aparentemente é a mais atual

Comment: Consegui!
Tive que mudar a versão do gcm para o mesmo que o firebase

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'